# Manual setup of Spring Data JPA repositories, with custom implementation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to manually define custom spring data repository, I have following 3 classes :

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>...

public interface PersonRepositoryCustom 

public class PersonRepositoryImpl implements PersonRepositoryCustom {
  @Resource
private PersonRepository personRepository;
......
}
```

To configure this in a Configuration class I have the following:

```
@Bean
public PersonRepositoryImpl personRepositoryImpl() {
return new PersonRepositoryImpl();
}

@Bean
public PersonRepository personRepository() {
    return getFactoryBean(PersonRepository.class, personRepositoryImpl());
}

private <T> T getFactoryBean(Class<T> repository, Object customImplementation) {
    BaseRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new BaseRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setEntityManager(entityManager);
    factory.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
    factory.setRepositoryInterface(repository);
    if (customImplementation != null) {
        factory.setCustomImplementation(customImplementation);
    }
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return (T) factory.getObject();

}
```

The problem I am having is that I am getting 
**"Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference"**

This seems to be due to the fact that the PersonRepositoryImpl  contains a resource reference to the personRepository interface.

If I use the EnableJpaRepositories on the config class then everything seems to work fine.
However I don't want to use that annotation, it scans based on packages, and I want more fine grained configurability.

So does anyone know how to manually setup a spring custom repository, that allows injection without the circular reference problem?

Anyone?

Comment: You can limit the scope of that package scan.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `CustomRepository` interface extending [`Repository<T,ID extends Serializable>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/repository/Repository.html). Then you can implement `CustomRepositoryImpl` by yourself if you want full control of your repositories. You can refer to [SimpleJpaRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java) as implementation example.